# Req flash with delay in express 4 app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

i'm using passport js with local strategy to authenticate my user into my webapp but i see a certain delay setting the flash message , i try using the {message : ''} option in passport and passing the request function an setting manually the flash message but the delay persist :

```
    passport.use(new LocalStrategy({passReqToCallback:true},
    (req,username,password,done)=>{
    userBl.getUserByUsername(username).then((user) => {
        if (user != null && user != undefined) {

            if (password == user.password) {
                return done(null,user)
            }
            else {
                return done(null,false,req.flash('error','Constraseña incorrecta'))
            }
        } else {
            return done(null,false,req.flash('error','usuario'))
        }



    });
}));
```

and call the error by req.flash('error') but is empty and after a second reload or certain time it show's the error and the flash value , any help . Thanks

it's this a normal delay with req flash or some error ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation http://passportjs.org/docs,
you should just pass something like

```
done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
```

But seems you're handling the error message by yourself now using

```
return done(null,false,req.flash('error','Constraseña incorrecta'))
```

Which might cause some kind of asynchronous issue I think.